# MatOfPoint cartesian coordinates

Tags: java, opencv

```
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    String filename = "cannystopa4.png";

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat rgbImage = Imgcodecs.imread("foto.jpg");
    Mat imageCny = new Mat();
    Imgproc.Canny(rgbImage, imageCny, 50, 150, 3, true);

    Imgproc.findContours(imageCny, contours , new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println(contours.get(i));
    }
```

How can I get cartesian coordinates from `Arraylist` of `MatOfPoint`?

Comment: Share the code where you are adding coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the contours list and for each MatOfPoint iterate the list of Point objects it contains.

```
for( MatOfPoint mop: contours ){
    for( Point p: mop.toList() ){
        ... p.x, p.y ... // another coordinate
    }
}
```